# Returning a user to a previous form based on their previous form

Tags: c#, methods, authentication

I have a program that has both a User page and an Admin page. A user or admin can navigate to a Zipcode lookup page. On that Zipcode lookup page, I have a back button. I want the program to return a user to the user page and an Admin to the admin page. In short, how do I make my C# Windows Forms program return a user/admin to the previous page they were on.

Also, nowhere on the Zipcode page is there any difference between user and Admin. It is exactly the same page with the same information e.g. I cant just do `ActiveForm.Hide();` and `MyAdmin.Show;`, or some sort of `if - else` statement.

Should I set their login status (either user or admin) as some sort of public method and use that? I feel there may be an easier way.

Comment: depending on how they `navigate to a Zipcode lookup page`, create a 'ReturnTo' object or flag property to track where they came from and use it to branch in the Return button click event

Comment: You'll need to learn how to use an event in your own code.  That Back button should just fire a Back event.  Whatever class displayed the form knows what to do in its event handler for the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass in the current form to the Show() method when you display the zipcode lookup page.  This will set the Owner() property.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show(this); // pass in the owner
    }

}
```

Now you can check for that in the second form and hide/show that form as appropriate:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += new EventHandler(Form2_Shown);
        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form2_FormClosed);
    }

    void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Owner != null)
        {
            this.Owner.Hide();
        }
    }

    void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Owner != null)
        {
            this.Owner.Show();
        }
    }

}
```

This doesn't have to be done from the FormClosed() event, you could do it just as well from your back button.

Comment: Or, if you change your paradigm slightly, simply **don't** hide the originating form.  Instead, display the zipcode lookup form with **ShowDialog()**.  Then the user will automatically return to the source form when the secondary form is closed.  You'd have both forms on the screen at once but the first wouldn't be accessible.  Also, you could technically hide the form first, call ShowDialog(), then show the form again.  That would all be done from within the first form, and wouldn't require any changes at all in the secondary.